# Sorting rows of dataframe in the order as they are without indexing problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe like this:

```
      col1 
0     A      
1     A
2     B
3     A
.
.
9     C
10    D
11    A
.
.

19    B
20    A
21    B
22    D
```

When I use `df.sort_values(by=['col1'])` it gives me a dataframe like this:

```
     col1 
0     A      
1     A
11    A
20    A
3     A
19    B
2     B
.
.
.
```

I want my values to be sorted in order with the right index and not index 11 or 20 before 3:

```
    col1 
0     A      
1     A
3     A
11    A
20    A
2     B
19    B
.
.
.
```

I tried `ignore_index=True` but it only corrects the index, the sorted rows are still wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `kind="mergesort"` for stable-sort:

```
print(df.sort_values(by="col1", kind="mergesort"))
```

Prints:

```
   col1
0     A
1     A
3     A
11    A
20    A
2     B
19    B
21    B
9     C
10    D
22    D
```